# Search Most Popular Pages with KeywordQuery

Tags: 2013, search, visual-web-part, keywordquery

In my Visual Web Part I need a KeywordQuery to search Most Popular Pages.  Also, filter the results for Pages only.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint oob rating to determine popularity or usage analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply added a sort by

```
KeywordQuery kq = new KeywordQuery(site);
kq.SortList.Add("ViewsLifeTime", SortDirection.Descending)
```